# Read file names from a list file one by one and create a md5 checksum list file in unix

Tags: shell, unix, md5sum

I have a list file  with file names listed:

```
List1.txt
File1
File2
File3
File4
```

I want to loop through the the file names in list 1 and generate another md5 checksum list file for each file present in the list 1.

Expected Output:

```
md5_list.txt
File1 MD5Value
File2 MD5Value
File3 MD5Value
File4 MD5Value
```

This is what i have come up with :

```
cat list1.txt | find -type f ! -name "list1.txt" -exec md5sum {} + | sort -k 2 > md5_list.txt
```

Would like to know if this is the right way ? If yes, is there a more efficient way of getting this done?

Thanks

Comment: why loop? Just pass them md5. `xargs md5sum < List1.txt`. The construct `md5sum $(cat list1.txt)` would help you understand. You already know the filenames, no need to `find` them.

Comment: With `sort`, `sort < List1.txt | xargs md5sum > md5_list.txt`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin this is quite simple and it works perfectly.

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

The solution given by [David C. Rankin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3422102/david-c-rankin) in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60729503/read-file-names-from-a-list-file-one-by-one-and-create-a-md5-checksum-list-file/60732057?noredirect=1#comment107447270_60729503) worked for me:

```
sort < List1.txt | xargs md5sum > md5_list.txt
```

Comment: Note that `md5sum` generates the MD5 checksum first and the file name second.  This is sensible; every MD5 checksum is the same length, but file names typically vary in length.  If it really matters, pipe the output of `md5sum` through `awk '{print $2, $1}'`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for the suggestion. I did try printing the output for check. Looks good. Thanks again.